# To prove: the set of all linear maps is a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am a total beginner reading Axler's *Linear Algebra Done Right*. In 3.5 , $T(v_j)=w_j$ is used where $v$'s & $w$'s are bases and $T:V\to W.$
I want to show that the set of all linear transformations is  a vector space. Addition of  $S,T$ in $L(V,W)$ is done by $(S + T)(v) = S(v)+T(v).$
My question is: can we have  $T(v_j)=w_j$ and $S(v_j)=w_j$ when  $S$ and $T$ are different ?

Comment: I would suggest to learn how the integrated latex compiler works: it would make your future post much easier to read. For a reference see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: No, we can't. But there are many other linear maps: for fixed $v_i$, their image can be *arbitrary* (not necessarily a basis, not alone specifically a fixed basis) elements of $W$.

Comment: Thanks .I should learn latex.

Comment: Berci  Then shouldn't one use a more general assignment between the bases than T(vj) = wj to show that T(u+v)= T(u) + T(v)  ?

Answer (score 0):

If $T$ and $S$ are linear transformations their values are determined by linearity by the values at the vectors of a basis. Thus if $T(v_i)=S(v_i)$ for any basis $\{v_i \}$ of $V$ then $T$ and $S$ must coincide.

Comment: To show T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)  should we start with T( a1j. v1j+ .... aNj. vNj) = wj  ... j= 1. to M:   M<= N , rather than T(vj)= wj  ?

Comment: @ccsiva To show? I don't think you are supposed to show that $T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v)$. You $\textbf{do}$ know that $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$, which makes it a linear operator by the very definition of the set $\mathcal{L}(V,W)$ (see Definitions and Examples in Axler, Chapter 3)

Answer (score 0):

Good question. Let's start by carefully defining when two operators are equal and when they are not. Consider two linear operators $T,S: V \mapsto W$ (or equivalently, $T, S \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$). We say that $T$ and $S$ are the same (or, equal to one another) *iff*:
$$T(u) = S(u) \text{ for all }u \in V$$
We say that $T$ and $S$ are *different* when:
$$\exists u \in V: T(u) \neq S(u) $$
which is simply the negation of the first statement. Suppose now we also have:
$$T(v_j) = w_j \text{ and } S(v_j) = w_j$$
where the sets
$$B_1 = \{v_1, ..., v_n \} \text{ and } B_2 =\{w_1,...,w_n \}$$
are bases of $V$ and $W$, respectively (the two spaces must have the same dimension). Now, for an arbitrary vector $u \in V$, there is a unique representation in the $B_1$ basis:
$$u = \sum_{j=1}^n a_i v_j$$
The action of $T$ to $u$ yields:
$$T(u) = T \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j v_j \right) = T (a_1 v_1 + ... + a_n v_n) = a_1 T(v_1) + ... + a_n T(v_n) \Longrightarrow$$
$$T(u) = \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j T(v_j) \right)$$
Likewise, the action of $S$ to $u$ is:
$$S(u) = \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j S(v_j) \right)$$
Thus, we trivially get:
$$T(u) = \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j T(v_j) \right) = \left( \sum_{j=1}^n a_j S(v_j) \right) = S(u) \Longrightarrow T(u) = S(u) \text{ for all }u \in V$$
which makes $T$ and $U$ equal. Thus, the answer to your question is **No** as we just proved that:
$$\text{if} \ T(v_i) = w_j \text{ and } S(v_j) = w_j \text{ for } 1 \leq j \leq n \Longrightarrow T(u) = S(u) \text{ for any } v \in V$$

Answer (score 0):

I made a huge mistake in understanding 3.5 of Axler's Done Right. T in L( V, W) .  In using
T(vj)= wj  ,( j= 1... N  ) , vj are the basis of V and wj are any N vectors in W.
I thought, wrongly , that wj are basis of W . This would imply dim V= dim W too .When the correct view is taken , that wj are any N vectors in W , we can have S in L(V,W)  different from T by
S(vj) = uj   . (uj   , j= 1... N  vectors ) in  W different from wj .